# How to print a Scanner's results on a screen

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, filewriter

I have a scanner that can read a txt file that I am trying to print on the screen. I am trying to do this by printing the scanner (scan) results of what the user typed in on the on the screen using Graphics g.

Any Ides on how to do this a different way
Thank You :)

```
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/AlexSpallone/Desktop/name.txt"));
      msg = " Your Name is" + scan;
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call the [nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method on your `Scanner` object:

```
try {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/AlexSpallone/Desktop/name.txt"));
  msg = " Your Name is" + scan.nextLine();
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: No i dont want it being wrote in the console I meant on a gui. How would I draw it using a string?

Comment: You would need to do what he is saying to get the string, but drawing it on the GUI is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to use text areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

```
String msg = null;
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/AlexSpallone/Desktop/name.txt"));
    msg = " Your Name is" + scan.nextLine();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(msg);
add(new JScrollPane(ta));
```

Equally, if it's just a small `String`, you could just use a `JLabel`.  See [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details

I'd also take a look at [Creating a UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponenet(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/AlexSpallone/Desktop/name.txt"));
            msg = " Your Name is" + scan.nextLine();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        g.drawString(20, 20, msg);
    }
}
```

Then add an object of this class to a `JFrame`.

Comment: Why?  Apart from the fact that if the file is a large file, it will block the EDT and make the program look like it's frozen, it won't handle things like long lines, word wrapping, scrolling etc...

Comment: I know. I was in a hurry to write an answer.

Comment: Give the OP doesn't seem to have any concept of Swing, throwing into the fire with the oil seems a little harsh - IMHO ;)

Comment: Then why didn't you fix your answer? Why haven't you yet fixed your answer yet? This is very bad advice that should either be repaired or deleted.